# Ruby: more readable way to write nested if conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a more readable way in Ruby (or using Rails model helpers) to write the following:

```
def get_question
    if self.is_question?
        self.trackable
    elsif self.is_answer?
        self.trackable.question
    elsif self.is_comment?
        if self.trackable.is_question?
            self.trackable.commentable
        elsif self.trackable.is_answer?
            self.trackable.commentable.question
        end
    end
end
```

There must be a more "Ruby way" of writing this so it's easier to read for other developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to write that sort of thing like this:

```
def get_question
  return self.trackable                      if  self.is_question? 
  return self.trackable.question             if  self.is_answer? 
  return nil                                 if !self.is_comment? 
  return self.trackable.commentable          if  self.trackable.is_question? 
  return self.trackable.commentable.question if  self.trackable.is_answer? 
  return nil
end
```

that's pretty mu-idiomatic but I don't know if it qualifies as Ruby-idiomatic. Yes, there's an unnecessary `return` at the end but I like the symmetry and how it makes everything visually line up.

In real life, I'd probably want replace all that logic with a `question` method on the `self.trackable`. Then each thing could implement `question` (or `to_question`, `get_question`, or whatever name made the most sense in the broader context):

```
# Inside questions...
def question
  self
end

# Inside answers...
# Nothing special needed, we've already got one.
```

and so on for the other possible possible `self.trackable` things. That would leave your `get_question` looking like this:

```
def get_question
  self.trackable.respond_to?(:question) ? self.trackable.question : nil
end
```

or you could do away with `get_question` completely if you knew that `self.trackable` would also respond to `question`.

Comment: I gave you +1 for the second half, as that's the sort of thing I'd do too. The `return ... if ...` format is not easy to follow in this example, but I suppose it serves to highlight that the OP needs to refactor along the lines that you suggest.

Comment: I really like the idea of the `respond_to`. That's awesome!

Comment: @KenY-N: Yeah, I agree that that format is a bit forced in this context, it tends to work better when you're unrolling `if a && b && c ...` constructs.

Comment: You can, and should, remove all the `self`s.

Comment: @sawa: Yes you can but I find the code a lot more readable if you leave them in.